# Determine threshold value of an image for performing global thresholding

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In order to perform global thresholding, the threshold value must be defined. But is that value related to intensity histogram ? SHould i choose it randomly or there is a way to determine it? (My output will be a binary image)

Thank you very much.

Comment: your question is very vague. What type of thresholding you wish to do? What type of binary image you expect to get? Do you have training data? Is your input a gray-scale image or a color image????

Comment: i want to perform intensity thresholding, on a grayscale image,and the result will be a binary image

Comment: use Otsu's method to threshold the intensity histogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search in the FEX yield many contributions by [Jan Motl](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/303241), for example:

- [Bradley local image thresholding](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40854-bradley-local-image-thresholding)
- [Nick local image thresholding](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42104-nick-local-image-thresholding)
- [Wolf local threshold](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42101-wolf-local-image-thresholding)
- [meanthresh local image thresholding](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41787-meanthresh-local-image-thresholding)
- [Feng local image thresholding](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41771-feng-local-image-thresholding)
- [Niblack local image thresholding](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40849-niblack-local-thresholding)
- [Sauvola local image thresholding](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40266-sauvola-local-image-thresholding)
- [Brensen local image thresholding](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40856-bernsen-local-image-thresholding)

A quick and dirty estimate of a global threshold to a grayscale image `img` will be:

```
 threshold = max([min(max(img,[],1))  min(max(img,[],2))]) ;
```

Another detailed yet basic treatment is found in [this FEX file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38390-basic-global-thresholding)

Comment: Is that estimate better than `threshold = rand` ?

Comment: Are you really asking me something you can't answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods that can be used for finding threshold values for binarization of an image. Refer to : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)

You can also use Otsu threshold, Kittler threshold and Adaptive binarization using these thresholds.